# Rails association - has at least one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model `ShippingOption`, which has_many `ShippingSpeedOptions`

And one requirement:

- A `ShippingOption` must have *at least one* `ShippingSpeedOption`, and this should be validated because it is removable in the interface

So I am using a custom validation on `ShippingOption`:

```
  def has_at_least_one_shipping_speed_option
    errors.add(:shipping_speed_options, "Must have at least one delivery speed package") if self.shipping_speed_options.count <= 0
  end
```

The problem is that with this validation, a `ShippingOption` can't be saved at all because it has no `ShippingSpeedOptions`. The association is defined by the `shipping_option_id` in `ShippingSpeedOption`.

How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `build`, which makes an "association in waiting", which will be created when the object is saved.

```
@shipping_option = ShippingOption.new
@shipping_option.shipping_speed_options.build(:shipping_speed => <speed>)
@shipping_option.save 
#at this point the validation is satisfied, @shipping_option is saved and the option is created.
```

Comment: What is the syntax / arguments for `build` ?

Comment: Okay I've changed `count` to `size` in my validation, now build works. Thank you!

Comment: The syntax is the same as for .new() : a hash of settermethod-value pairs (curly braces optional).  It's really like .new that also makes the association.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting.  I suppose .count ALWAYS just makes a db query, whereas size will look to see if there are any loaded association objects first, then build the db query if not.